# Prove $f$ is continuous with respect to the induced metric

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$X$ is a normed vector space with norm $f: X \rightarrow \Bbb R$. Prove that $f$ is continuous w.r.t the induced metric, namely $d(x,y) = f(x-y)$.

I already proved by triangular inequality that $\forall x,y \in X$, have $|f(x)-f(y)| \le f(x-y)$. I'm not sure if this could help with the proof. Could someone provide a complete proof of the problem please? Thanks.

Comment: This actually is the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 s.t. \forall x, y \in X, d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$

So you already have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq f(x-y)$

But $d(x,y) = f(x-y)$

let $\epsilon > 0$ be given assume $d(x,y) < \delta$. Let $\delta = \epsilon$

Then by  $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq f(x-y) < \delta = \epsilon $

So $f$ is continuous.